# entity is not rendering react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, entities

I have a react.js application with changed status.
I want to display to user some data using `Entity`.
The problem is, in the first time being rendered it's ok, but the component do not response to the changes behind.
This works fine:

```
getPaymentData() {
    let data = "";
    switch (this.props.params.type) {
        case "success":
            if (this.state.validate)
                data = 'The_payment_was_received' ;
            else
                data = 'Checking' ;
            break;
        case "error":
            data='There_was_an_error';
            break;
        case "cancel":
            data='The_payment_was_canceled' ;
            break;
    }
    return  data
}
```

and in the render method:

```
<h2 style={{marginBottem :"10px"}}>   { ::this.getPaymentData()} </h2>
```

but -  when I do this, it is not responding.

```
case "cancel":
    data='The_payment_was_canceled';
    break;
}
return  <Entity entity= data>
```

or

```
<h2 style={{marginBottem :"10px"}}>  <Entity entity={ ::this.getPaymentData()} /> </h2>
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

`<Entity entity= data>` is incorrect. Use

`<Entity entity={ ::this.getPaymentData()} />` seems incorrect to me. Why `::` is for? Use